# Can (x++ !== x) && (x++ === x); return true?

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine come across this question at an interview

Find a value of x that will make this function return true

```
function f(x) {
    return (x++ !== x) && (x++ === x);
}
```

The interviewer added: x should be **5** **characters** max

I found multiple answers of 7 characters:

```
[["2**53-1"],["2*3**33"],["2-5**23"],["5**23-2"],["3**33*2"]]
```

But I couldn't find the one with 5 characters. (not even 6) . I was doubting that there is a solution that has 5 characters. But after research, I found this site: https://alf.nu/ReturnTrue that offers the same challenge and  it turns out there is (are) solution(s) with 5 characters:

[image]

Can someone please help to know what is it?

Comment: Woah... But how is this even possible?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It works because it's on the edge of integer precision that Double has.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ah, then it's using up the limitation and it's a hack. `:P`

Comment: I did see this: [return true to win](https://gist.github.com/cmilfont/1469790766cff5849ed8515349ee2a77)

Comment: Being asked that question at an interview would tell me everything I wanted to know about the hiring company

Comment: The only legitimate way to use this in an interview is to see the candidate's way of approaching this problem; not whether they can actually get the correct solution or not. Knowing this kind of thing makes you a good code golfer, it says nothing about your ability to be a good developer.

Comment: `1e16+2` would be a 6-character solution.

Comment: https://pvdz.ee/weblog/378#peano is saying that it's `peano(9**17)` but it doesn't work for me. I notice the solutions all use chrome so it could be browser dependent.

Comment: @fgb There is no solution for Chrome under Linux using exponentiation. Given we have 5 characters, that leaves 3 digits left to test for n**m, which is trivial to test and does not find anything.

Comment: Note that *all* 5-character solutions are from Chrome users.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple to do exhaustive search for solutions using different operations.

Since the only solutions that make `f` true are values `>=` than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, we immediately think of exponentiation or scientific notation to achieve them in a small space.

---

## Exponentation

We use 2 characters, and we are left with only 3 for digits:

```
// n**mm
for (n = 0; n <= 9; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 99; ++m)
    if (f(n**m))
        console.log(n, m, n**m);

// nn**m
for (n = 0; n <= 99; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 9; ++m)
    if (f(n**m))
        console.log(n, m, n**m);
```

Since there are only 3 digits left, we cannot use an addition/subtraction here to offset things (it takes at least 2 characters).

---

## Scientific notation

We use 1 character, so we are left with 4 potential digits:

```
// nEmmm
for (n = 0; n <= 9; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 999; ++m)
    if (f(n*(10**m)))
        console.log(n, m, n*(10**m));

// nnEmm
for (n = 0; n <= 99; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 99; ++m)
    if (f(n*(10**m)))
        console.log(n, m, n*(10**m));

// nnnEm
for (n = 0; n <= 999; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 9; ++m)
    if (f(n*(10**m)))
        console.log(n, m, n*(10**m));
```

However, in this case we can do addition/subtraction:

```
// nEm+d
for (n = 0; n <= 9; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 9; ++m)
for (d = 0; d <= 9; ++d)
    if (f(n*(10**m)+d))
        console.log(n, m, d, n*(10**m)+d);

// nEm-d
for (n = 0; n <= 9; ++n)
for (m = 0; m <= 9; ++m)
for (d = 0; d <= 9; ++d)
    if (f(n*(10**m)-d))
        console.log(n, m, d, n*(10**m)-d);
```

---

## Full expression search

We can also do a full exhaustive search over the entire string space considering that it is only 5 characters.

To speed it up a bit, let's only use characters that we think can actually get us there (e.g. the digits, the arithmetic operators, etc). If we use 24 characters like below, that is `24**5` possibilities, which is only a few millions to test (it should take only a minute or so in a modern computer):

```
const s = [
    "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
    "e",".",
    "*","+","-","/","%",
    "!","^","&","|","<",">","~"
];
const l = s.length;
for (var n1 = 0; n1 < l; ++n1)
for (var n2 = 0; n2 < l; ++n2)
for (var n3 = 0; n3 < l; ++n3)
for (var n4 = 0; n4 < l; ++n4)
for (var n5 = 0; n5 < l; ++n5)
    try {
        const expr = s[n1] + s[n2] + s[n3] + s[n4] + s[n5];
        if (f(eval(expr)))
            console.log(expr);
    } catch (e) {};
```

Note: we have to use `try...catch`, since many of the expressions will be invalid. Also, be careful with the variable names you use (e.g. if you use `e` as a loop counter, you will get strings like `--e` which will get you into an infinite loop!

Comment: Maybe "it is simple", but it doesn't lead to a solution, does it? If it's not an answer, then maybe you should add a sentence on top that clearly states that this is only a partial/unsuccessful solution attempt.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It does lead to a solution, *if there is one*. For my environment, there isn't any; but other people reported (before they deleted the answer) at least one 5-char solution that worked somewhere. Since we cannot be expected to test every single platform, I provided an answer to find the solutions in different ways.